# What is Brute-force descriptor matcher?

Tags: opencv, feature-descriptor

I need the explanation for Brute-force descriptor matcher. What is Brute-force descriptor matcher ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Brute-force` means basic or naive descriptor matcher, like knn or radius. 
find this: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html